# Testflight app requires iOS8. How do we beta test with iOS7?

Tags: ios, testing, app-store-connect, testflight, beta

Now that Apple have integrated Tesflight into itunesconnect I thought it was time I took a look.

I have fallen at the first hurdle - when you invite a tester to test an app they are told they must have the Testflight app installed on their device, but the Testflight app requires iOS8 or later and if you have iOS7 it seems you can't be a tester.

So my question is...am i missing something and is there a way to use Apple's new Testflight beta testing system with iOS7 users?

Comment: The tester should use an iOS 8 device to download the Testflight app on his iTunes account and then try to redownload it from the iOS 7 device; it should tell him that the latest version requires iOS 8 but he can download the last version that supports iOS 7. Not sure if the actual Testflight app will work after being installed, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I came across the same issue recently without having found a proper workaround or solution

Comment: Use Crashlytics Beta or HockeyApp instead.

Comment: @ahwulf I may just have to check these other systems out. Thanks

Comment: Or Roboto :) Much better than both!

Comment: yes, great work apple... you took a perfectly fine working system and transformed it into something useless... just great

Comment: @RaduSimionescu I'm using HockeyApp quite a lot now. I recommend it!

Comment: @Tokn yeah, already looking into it. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

TestFlight supports iOS 8 and up.

> You can use TestFlight on up to 10 devices and test multiple apps for
>   multiple developers — there is no limit to the number of apps that you
>   can test simultaneously. TestFlight can be used to test iOS apps on
>   iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch running **iOS 8 or later**. Mac apps cannot
>   be tested. If the beta app does not load on your device, contact the
>   developer.

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)

---

For the time being, until we'll drop iOS 7 support, we use [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) for all of our beta testing.

I'd also like to add that for a free service, Crashlytics gave us the best support so far.

Comment: I second that. Awesome support from Crashlytics.

Comment: You mean for internal beta testing only, right? Don't think Apple allows AdHoc testing for external distribution (outside your company)

Answer (score 6):

[Testfairy](http://www.testfairy.com/), a competitor of Testflight, have confirmed with a timely email that Apple's Testflight doesn't support iOS7, so this is a *fact*.

Testfairy, conveniently, do support iOS7:

> As you have probably heard, Apple has announced that on February 26,
>   the TestFlight website will be shut down and all iOS developers will
>   be forced to migrate their apps to the new TestFlight service
>   available inside of iTunes Connect.
>
> This migration is highly problematic for developers due to Apple’s lack of support of testing
>   options for iOS7 that still runs on 25% of iOS devices, as well as
>   delays caused by manual reviews.
>
> TestFairy now supports both Android
>   and iOS with the strongest feature set in the market.
>
> To avoid losing
>   your testers’ UDIDs you need to export your testers’ device
>   information.

Comment: Meh. Downvote for some reason. I've just used the Testfairy import tool and I can report it was an effortless transition. And no, I don't own shares.

Comment: For me it fails installing TestFairy ios build on devices running ios6.
So TestFairy supports only ios 7 and higher ?